NetBeans 23 does not open on Mac OS
I just bought a new MacBook Pro m1pro with Sequoia 15.1 installed. I just installed Netbeans IDE 23. When I click on the app it won't open. I installed and reinstalled multiple times and restarted the computer.
I installed and reinstalled multiple times and restarted the computer.

first step would probably be to install the ARM version of Java.

Explain exactly what "it won't open" means.

You do not provide enough details to diagnose.
Certainly Java runs well on macOS on MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon chips such as M1 Pro.
Tips:

Be sure to install a JDK/JRE made for Apple Silicon (M1, M2, M3, M4 chips), if that is the chip in your Mac.

I prefer using SDKMAN! to locate, download, install, and uninstall your JDKs/JREs. You will find several, but not all, vendors available.


Download the NetBeans installer named with .pkg, which means specifically for macOS. Example: Apache-NetBeans-23.pkg

Check the SHA-512 hash to verify you downloaded successfully with no corruption.



The SDKMAN! tool will automatically default to showing JDK/JRE products specific to your chip. In your case you should see: Available Java Versions for macOS ARM 64bit.
Apple Silicon may be identified in some products as ARM or Aarch64.

You actually can install and run an implementation of Java built for Intel chips on a Mac with an Apple Silicon chip. Java-for-Intel will run due to the amazing Rosetta 2 technology. But there is no point, no upside, when there are plenty of good Java implementations available for Apple Silicon chips.

You should install NetBeans with this link: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/netbeans/netbeans-installers/23/Apache-NetBeans-23.pkg
Using Apple Silicon M3:


same here... the .pkg file installed. the application is correctly found in launchpad and in /applications/ but when clicked seemingly nothing happens although I think I see the icon pop and then close in an instant on the dock.

This is not an answer but rather a comment.

You need to install jdk first.
